# Create socket connection with NTLM proxy authorization in C#

Tags: c#, websocket, ntlm

Our app is working with websocket service using WebSocket4Net library.
http://websocket4net.codeplex.com
Unfortunately, it have very limited proxy support. Something like this:
https://clientengine.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Proxy/HttpConnectProxy.cs

They just compose HTTP request manually as string. I was able to add Proxy-authorization header there for basic authorization and it works, but some of our clients have proxy with NTLM authorization. So, I probably need to do something like this:
http://www.innovation.ch/personal/ronald/ntlm.html

Is there easy way to accomplish that, rather then generating all those 3 messages myself?
HttpWebRequest is able to connect through that proxy. But I need to do the same with the Socket.

Using .net 4.5 is not an option. We need to support Windows XP.